# yii cgridview expression evaluation does not work on pagination

Tags: yii, expression, evaluation, cgridview

I have the following cgrid view which works and evalutes and displays the 1st 18 results as pagination is set to 18.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'projects-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(false),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'rowCssClassExpression'=>'($data->PERCENT == 100)? "yellow" : ($row%2?"even":"odd")',
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'  =>  'PROJID',
            'htmlOptions'   =>  array('style'=>'width:70px'),
        ),
        array(
            "header"=>"Client",
            "value"=>' ($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID == "")? "" : (isset($data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTold->COMPANY))? $data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTold->COMPANY:  (isset($data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTsugar->name)) ? $data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTsugar->name : "" ',//'(strlen($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID)>10) ? $data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTsugar->name : ""',//(isset($data->oRDERNO->aCcounts0->COMPANY)) ? $data->oRDERNO->aCcounts0->COMPANY : "" '
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'PROJECT',
            'header'=>"Project",
            'type' => 'raw',
            'filter'=>$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'attribute'=>'PROJECT',
                'model'=>$model,
                'name'=>'Projects[PROJECT]',
                'options'=>array(
                        'minLength'=>'2',
                ),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                            'id' => 'Projects_PROJECT_search'
                    ),
            ),true),
        ),
        'country',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update}{view}',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:5px'),   
            //"style"=>"width:5px"
            'buttons'=>array(
                    'update'=>array(
                            'visible'=>'(isset($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID)) ?  (strlen($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID)>10) ? true :false: false',
                    ),
                    /*'view'=>array(
                            'visible'=>'(isset($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID)) ?  (strlen($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID)>10) ? true :false: false',
                    ),*/
            ),  

        ),      
    ),  
)); ?>
```

How ever when i try to got next it errors.

```
<h1>PHP Error [8]</h1>
<p>Trying to get property of non-object (/opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/base/CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code:1)</p>
<pre>#0 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/base/CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code(1): CWebApplication->handleError()
#1 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/base/CComponent.php(612): eval()
#2 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CDataColumn.php(137): CDataColumn->evaluateExpression()
#3 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridColumn.php(151): CDataColumn->renderDataCellContent()
#4 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php(616): CDataColumn->renderDataCell()
#5 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php(572): CGridView->renderTableRow()
#6 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php(482): CGridView->renderTableBody()
#7 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php(167): CGridView->renderItems()
#8 unknown(0): CGridView->renderSection()
#9 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php(150): preg_replace_callback()
#10 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php(135): CGridView->renderContent()
#11 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CBaseController.php(173): CGridView->run()
#12 /opt/paradox/protected/views/projects/entry.php(90): ProjectsController->widget()
#13 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CBaseController.php(126): require()
#14 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CBaseController.php(95): ProjectsController->renderInternal()
#15 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(869): ProjectsController->renderFile()
#16 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(782): ProjectsController->renderPartial()
#17 /opt/paradox/protected/controllers/ProjectsController.php(811): ProjectsController->render()
#18 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): ProjectsController->actionAdmin()
#19 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#20 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(286): ProjectsController->runAction()
#21 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(265): ProjectsController->runActionWithFilters()
#22 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): ProjectsController->run()
#23 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#24 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#25 /opt/paradox/index.php(31): CWebApplication->run()
</pre>
```

Comment: exactly where you are getting this error? that line may be highlighted red or pink

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe on your second page you are missing things. 1 example might be that 
$data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID is not existent. If there is no $data->oRDERNO then accessing $data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID would thrown an error exactly how you see it. try getting to the second page in the browser to see that this is the case.

Comment: all `$data` records have the relation `oRDERNO`

Comment: Just go to the second page and see the error in full. (right on the pagination, open in new tab). If that is not it then it is something exactly like that.

Comment: it won't let me browse to 2nd page. the error i receive is what i posted above

Comment: I have tried `"value"=>' (!isset($data->oRDERNO) || $data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID == "")? "" : (isset($data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTold->COMPANY))? $data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTold->COMPANY:  (isset($data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTsugar->name)) ? $data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTsugar->name : "" ',` doesn't work either

Comment: Try commenting out parts of the view until you find the exact place where the problem is. Maybe that part does not have a problem, but another part has a problem.

Comment: i used a different condition to solve it `'(isset($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID)) ?  (strlen($data->oRDERNO->ACCOUNTID)>10) ? $data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTsugar->name :$data->oRDERNO->aCCOUNTold->COMPANY: false',`